# IPv6 traffic shaping

Tags: ipv6, traffic-shaping, m0n0wall

With the second [IPv6 Launch Day](http://www.worldipv6launch.org/) behind us, i'm stuck waiting for traffic shaping support on IPv6 before i can deploy it to our network.

- i currently use [m0n0wall](http://m0n0.ch/wall/) as a router with its IPv6 support, but [it does not support shaping of IPv6 traffic](http://forum.m0n0.ch/index.php?topic=2715.0)
- [pfSense](http://www.pfsense.org/) (a branch of m0n0wall) does not [support IPv6](http://forum.pfsense.org/index.php/board,52.0.html)

Is there any pc-based router that supports traffic shaping of IPv6?

Answer (score 3):

## traffic shaping ipv6 using tc for linux

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb default 30
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 256kbit
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:2 htb rate 256kbit
tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ipv6 parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip6 dst 2001:a:b:c::2/64 flowid 1:1
tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ipv6 parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip6 src 2001:a:b:c::2/64 flowid 1:2
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a Linux box with a dual IP stack and iptables/tc?

Shorewall appears to do IPv6 based traffic shaping.
http://www.shorewall.net/simple_traffic_shaping.html

Comment: pfSense and m0n0wall *are* \*nix boxes. Shorewall takes a set of less-complicated config files, parsing them to convert them into the required more-complicated config files.

Comment: both pfSense and m0n0wall are BSD based.  I suggested using just a simple Linux machine with the basic OS and building your own as opposed to relying on someone else's implementation of the rules.  I have use a Linux machine for tunneling, shaping and firewalling IPv6 without issue just using the basic iptables/tc tools.

Comment: i would get to the point where i have to type stuff at a shell prompt and fall over dead from frustration. i'm looking for someone else to do the grunt work. (i.e. a router)

Comment: There really isn't one for *nix out of the box written for IPv6 specifically.  You can always throttle Protocol 41 (IPv6-in-IPv4) but my advice would be to move up to Cisco hardware and implement IPv6 QoS.  http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/ipv6/configuration/guide/ip6-qos.html